# Setting no-cache after a cache has occurred?

Tags: http, no-cache

I recently got some errors due to the browser reusing some cached js bundles.

Initially, the response serving the bundles **did not have** any `Cache-Control` headers. After the error, I added them but unfortunately, the issue persisted.

Question: **Would adding the no-cache headers affect browsers that have already cached the js bundles?** At what point does the cache validation happen? Is it that when the browser needs to make a request to given path:

1. It will first check cache and then make request if cache-miss (hence no visibility on the newly added no-cache headers).
2. Make request only for headers, make cache validation and then actual request if cache-miss (hence it has visibility on the newly added headers)

This is probably a very beginner question, but I couldn't get a clear answer from googling

Comment: If the browser does not feel inclined in the first place, to check with the server again, whether the resource might have expired - then no, of course you can not do this.

Comment: Right, so validation happens on the client side prior to making any requests. Feel free to put as an answer, thanks